# ORACLE 10g: Reset Sequences from remote database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have remote database that needs to be replicated that is used by the team. I created a database link and a synonym that gives access to all_sequences table from the remote.

```
create synonym rprod_all_sequences for all_sequences@rprod_production;
```

Now I created an sql file that would get all users sequences and alter them to start at the correct number.

```
set serveroutput on
/******************************************************************************/
/* RESET ALL SEQUENCE NUMBERS                                                 */
/******************************************************************************/

declare 
cursor c_cursor is 
  select sequence_owner||'.'||sequence_name AS name, TO_CHAR(last_number + 1) AS last_number
    from rprod_all_sequences
     where sequence_owner not in ('WMSYS','XDB','SYS','SYSTEM','SYSMAN','MDSYS','LBACSYS','EXFSYS','DMSYS','DBSNMP','CTXSYS');

begin
 for r_record in c_cursor loop
    execute immediate 'alter sequence ' || r_record.name || ' ' ||' INCREMENT BY '|| r_record.last_number ||';';
  end loop;

end;
/
exit;
```

But I'm always getting this error:

```
sqlplus@RPROD> @reset_seq.sql
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

I'm not sure why it is complaining about the script as I tried it separately and it is working. Sorry this might be a noob question. Any ideas as to why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got an extra `;` at the end of your execute immediate statement. Try this:

```
 DECLARE
   CURSOR c_cursor
   IS
      SELECT sequence_owner || '.' || sequence_name AS name,
             TO_CHAR (last_number + 1) AS last_number
        FROM rprod_all_sequences
       WHERE sequence_owner NOT IN ('WMSYS',
                                    'XDB',
                                    'SYS',
                                    'SYSTEM',
                                    'SYSMAN',
                                    'MDSYS',
                                    'LBACSYS',
                                    'EXFSYS',
                                    'DMSYS',
                                    'DBSNMP',
                                    'CTXSYS');
BEGIN
   FOR r_record IN c_cursor
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
            'alter sequence '
         || r_record.name
         || ' '
         || ' INCREMENT BY '
         || r_record.last_number
          ;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: i get this error -> `DECLARE ERROR at line 1: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist ORA-06512: at line 21` it seems that the command is correct however the omitted ';' at the end makes the whole loop of commands into 1. I outputted the execute immediate by using dbms_ouput.put_line and test 1 script it works

Comment: You are running this in loop. So only 1 statement is getting executed once. Unlike you tried to print it via `dbms_output.put_line`. Please check incase the squence exists. It might happen that some sequences would not have created or already dropped. Put a exception block to find out actually issue.